# Docker Compose with VPN access

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vpn

I am having problems in my docker container with a VPN connection:

My container is unable to access internal hosts (which are available through VPN connection)
I tried temporarily setting `network_mode: host` in `docker-compose.yml` file, after which I was able to "ping" the host I needed, but because of this, the container was unable to communicate with other containers (e.g. mysql, etc)

So is it possible to use "bridge" network between containers, meanwhile "inheriting" the host network configurations ?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, Docker Version is 20.10.7, DockerCompose version is 1.25.0.